# Required comments field in ProcessInstanceWorkitemWizardStageManager

Tags: validation, approval-process, approval-step, page-validation

How do I enforce the comments is required field before the user approve/reject the request?

Below is my screen shot of the page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @Nick Kahn I found a post it will be very helpfull. You need to write a trigger on your object and query process instance.

Here the link step-by-step procedure with test class.

[Approval Comments mandatory](http://christopheralunlewis.blogspot.in/2012/10/making-all-approval-comments-mandatory.html)

Thanks to Christopher Alun Lewis for awesome post.I hope it will be helpfull for you.